# empty column after csv import in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in MySql, one of the columns is declared not null. I want to import a CSV file that has an ID field with no values to be imported. There is a script that generates an auto-generated ID. Can anyone tell me how to import the table with empty ID columns or if I can generate an auto-generated alphanumeric id in the CSV file?

The PHP script generates the ID as auto-generated field. The auto-generated is something like 4eac609ca0e99 and only the last 5 digits are changing.

Comment: It's empty, but it's also auto-generating alphanumeric?

Comment: that the issue.. the CSV file id column is empty but what I need to do is import it and the php script generates an autogenrated id like the one I said above..

Comment: But its not working.. I arranged the csv file as the number of fields in the table.

Comment: If the php script is generating the id, how is empty when you try to load it??

Comment: Do you have any code in place to do this now? Because if I understand you right you are going to need to do quite a bit to get this working. You need scripts to import and open the csv, extract and organise data, generate and include unique IDs and the connect to and insert into the database...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use custom ID generator when importing with phpMyAdmin or, I presume, any other tools.

I'd suggest to allow NULL in the problematic column, import your data using phpMyAdmin, then use your script to assign IDs to imported rows once they're in the table, then set NOT NULL for the column again.

If this table is live and thus already in use so it is supposed to contain only correct data, create another table with the same structure apart from NOT NULL, do the import, assign ids when scripts, then do INSERT INTO `live_table` SELECT * FROM `imported_table`.